# javascript read ads names

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, adsense, ads

**Problem**
on adsence they dont tell you which ads are showing and which not, because lots of ads i dont want them to show, because it has some content, which goes against our community policy, like bikini girls or vigra ads or many others.

**Solution Idea**
i wanted to know if its possible to read what adsense ads showing on my website through javascript. well the reason i asked, is because they are using iframe for ads. all i want to do, is read there showing ads and log it. which i can later review it, if i need to block thous ads or no. i might even just put report ads link, which will auto names of the current ads showing.

Little Sample Code

```
  var iframeID = jQuery('iframe').attr('id');           

        console.log(document.getElementById(iframeID).contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);

    output:
    <script>(function(){window.ss=function(d,e){window.status=d;var c=document.getElementById(e);if(c){var a;a=c.href;var b=a.match("^(.*)([?|&]nm=)([^&]*)(.*)$");if(b){b[3]=(Number(b[3])||0)+1;b[0]="";a=b.join("")}else a=a+"&nm=1";c.href=a}return true};})();function su(id) {var a = document.getElementById(id);var b = (new Date()).getTime();if (a && a.myt && b) {var t = b - a.myt;var bi = a.href.indexOf("&clkt=");if (bi > 0) {var c = a.href.substring(0, bi+6); var d = a.href.substring(bi+6, a.href.length);var ei = d.indexOf("&");var r = '';if (ei >= 0)r = d.substring(ei, d.length);a.href = c + t + r; } else {a.href += "&clkt=" + t;}}return true;}function cs(){window.status='';} function jcc(a) {pha=document.getElementById(a); nc=pha.href.indexOf('&jca='); if(nc>=1) return; jca=(401)+(344)-(324); if (a=='aw0') {jca+=(6844);} else {jca=0;} phb=pha.href+'&jca='+jca; pha.href=phb;} function st(id) {var a = document.getElementById(id);if (a) {a.myt = (new Date()).getTime();}return true;}function ha(a){  var pha=document.getElementById(a);var nhi=pha.href.indexOf("&nh=");if(nhi < 1) {pha.href+="&nh=1";}su(a); jcc(a); }function ca(a) {  var pha=document.getElementById(a);var nci=pha.href.indexOf("&nc=");if(nci < 1) {pha.href+="&nc=1";}su(a); jcc(a); top.location.href=document.getElementById(a).href;}function ga(o,e) {if (document.getElementById) {a=o.id.substring(1);p="";r="";g=e.target;if (g) {t=g.id;f=g.parentNode;if (f) {p=f.id;h=f.parentNode;if (h)r=h.id;}} else {h=e.srcElement;f=h.parentNode;if (f)p=f.id;t=h.id;}if (t==a||p==a||r==a)return true;var pha=document.getElementById(a);var nbi=pha.href.indexOf("&nb=");if(nbi < 1) {pha.href+="&nb=1";}su(a); jcc(a); top.location.href=document.getElementById(a).href;}}</script><script>document.close();</script>
```

**when i preview the iframe code in console, then this above code is in the header and body has all the ads**

```
following is the iframe code which i preview in console:
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active {
    color: #0000ff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

body,table,div,ul,li {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}

body {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100%
}

#aus {
    height: 250px;
    width: 300px
}

#ads {
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 300px
}

#ads ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#ads ul li {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: 232px;
    margin: 0px 21px 0px 21px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 258px
}

.ad {
    margin: 0px 0px
}

.adt {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.adb {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.adu {
    color: #009900;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap
}

.adus {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.adc {
    height: 232px;
    overflow: hidden;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%
}

#ainw {
    left: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 235px
}

#abgi {
    left: 202px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 233px
}

#aubg {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 0px solid #ffffff;
    height: 250px;
    width: 300px
}
</style>
<script>(function(){window.ss=function(d,e){window.status=d;var c=document.getElementById(e);if(c){var a;a=c.href;var b=a.match("^(.*)([?|&amp;]nm=)([^&amp;]*)(.*)$");if(b){b[3]=(Number(b[3])||0)+1;b[0]="";a=b.join("")}else a=a+"&amp;nm=1";c.href=a}return true};})();function su(id) {var a = document.getElementById(id);var b = (new Date()).getTime();if (a &amp;&amp; a.myt &amp;&amp; b) {var t = b - a.myt;var bi = a.href.indexOf("&amp;clkt=");if (bi &gt; 0) {var c = a.href.substring(0, bi+6); var d = a.href.substring(bi+6, a.href.length);var ei = d.indexOf("&amp;");var r = '';if (ei &gt;= 0)r = d.substring(ei, d.length);a.href = c + t + r; } else {a.href += "&amp;clkt=" + t;}}return true;}function cs(){window.status='';} function jcc(a) {pha=document.getElementById(a); nc=pha.href.indexOf('&amp;jca='); if(nc&gt;=1) return; sv=String.fromCharCode(49,49,51,56,57,55,49,56,51); sv=sv.slice(0,4); jca=(4446)+parseInt(sv); if (a=='aw0') {jca+=(-929);} else {jca=0;} phb=pha.href+'&amp;jca='+jca; pha.href=phb;} function st(id) {var a = document.getElementById(id);if (a) {a.myt = (new Date()).getTime();}return true;}function ha(a){  var pha=document.getElementById(a);var nhi=pha.href.indexOf("&amp;nh=");if(nhi &lt; 1) {pha.href+="&amp;nh=1";}su(a); jcc(a); }function ca(a) {  var pha=document.getElementById(a);var nci=pha.href.indexOf("&amp;nc=");if(nci &lt; 1) {pha.href+="&amp;nc=1";}su(a); jcc(a); window.open(document.getElementById(a).href);}function ga(o,e) {if (document.getElementById) {a=o.id.substring(1);p="";r="";g=e.target;if (g) {t=g.id;f=g.parentNode;if (f) {p=f.id;h=f.parentNode;if (h)r=h.id;}} else {h=e.srcElement;f=h.parentNode;if (f)p=f.id;t=h.id;}if (t==a||p==a||r==a)return true;var pha=document.getElementById(a);var nbi=pha.href.indexOf("&amp;nb=");if(nbi &lt; 1) {pha.href+="&amp;nb=1";}su(a); jcc(a); window.open(document.getElementById(a).href);}}</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="aus">
<div id="aubg"></div>
<div id="ads">
<ul id="ads0">
    <li onmouseover="ss('','aw0')" onfocus="ss('','aw0')" id="taw0">
    <div class="ad">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="adc">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle"><a target="_blank"
                    onmouseover="return ss('','aw0')" onmousedown="st('aw0')"
                    onfocus="ss('','aw0')" onclick="ha('aw0')" id="aw0"
                    href="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=ByWWG079CTeSRJI2MsgaAx93rBaCluFLmxLGnBsCNtwHAqQcQARgBIL39zQo4AFDVluesBWDL9LQFsgEQYmFzaXQuaXJlc2FsYS5pbboBCjMwMHgyNTBfYXPIAQHaASNodHRwOi8vYmFzaXQuaXJlc2FsYS5pbS9wUDJFU3NBYUpocuABAqkCigtjQVkTpT7gAgDqAhtzb2NpYWxfbWVkaWFfZGV0YWlsXzMwMHgyNTCQA_wHmAOkA6gDAcgDF-gDhAf1AwAAAMTgBAE&amp;num=1&amp;sig=AGiWqty6HglfRNFl5bjFjEG438XjgFQw3w&amp;client=ca-pub-&amp;adurl=http://www.gepaelk.com"
                    class="adt"><span>Reaktif Güç Kont. Rölesi</span></a>
                <div class="adb">Kompanzasyonda kesin çözüm. Klasik ve
                Thiristörlü çözümler.</div>
                <div class="adu"><span onmousedown="st(this.id.substr(1))"
                    onclick="ga(this,event)" id="uaw0" class="adus">www.gepaelk.com</span></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<img width="11" height="11"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/images/ainw_000000.gif"
    id="ainw" alt="">
<div id="abgi"><a target="_blank"
    href="http://www.google.com/url?ct=abg&amp;q=https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/request.py%3Fcontact%3Dabg_afc%26url%3Dhttp://basit.iresala.im/pP2ESsAaJhr%26hl%3Dtr%26client%3Dca-pub-%26adU%3Dwww.gepaelk.com%26adT%3DReaktif%2BG%25C3%25BC%25C3%25A7%2BKont.%2BR%25C3%25B6lesi%26gl%3DPK&amp;usg=AFQjCNGXuz2ZcyVIMFSpO3el2DEDVHZQkw"><img
    width="96" height="16" border="0"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/abglogo/abg-tr-100c-000000.png"
    alt="Google Reklamları"></a></div>
</div>
<script>document.close();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

so any ideas/solution please.

Comment: If the iframe is displaying content from another domain - which it most likely is - then you won't have any access to it at all with JavaScript. Also I would assume it's most likely against the terms to manipulate the ads. If you don't like the ads they are showing, then contact them and ask if they offer family friendly ads, and if not change to a company that does.

Comment: no its not manipulating, they have block list feature.. all we have to do is to know which ads showing and then the ads we dont like, put that in there block list, which would work perfectly. btw again, i dont need to manipulate it, i just need to read what ads showing to my users.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

its simple

```
        console.log(jQuery('iframe').contents().find('#ads0').html());
```

Answer (score -1):

No matter how good your intentions, the Single Origin Policy will block any access to the ad. There is no way around it using pure JavaScript inside the page.

You might, however, be able to set something up using a dedicated computer, a browser and a automation solution like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to record displayed ads. I expect it's going to be rather tough to implement, though.

Comment: there is already site doing it, but its not really good. adsblocklist.com.  btw i got it done, i dont need anything more. but thanks

Comment: btw if google tells you to kill yourself, you not gonna do it for good reasons, why just do exactly as they always say. they dont even care about our users privacy. if you go check google buzz news or even new location on search engine, you will find thousands of ppl upset from there carelesss actions, why should we care? anyway, im not worried about them blocking the site, cause it wont be just one one site, it will free service for everyone to use and gain the list of block ads. but honestly i really appreciate you guys for even just your thoughts. :)